# Java get generic type of static method at runtime

Tags: java, generics

So I was reading through the source code of `Collections.java`, there is a generic method `copy()`.

I simplified it to this:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
    System.out.println(dest.getClass());
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
        dest.set(i, src.get(i));
}
```

It makes sense syntactically, since `dest` is consumer and `src` is producer, but I really want to know what is `T` here.

For example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Number> dest = new ArrayList<>(5) {
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    add(null);
            }
        };

        List<Integer> src = new ArrayList<>(5) {
            {
                add(1);
                add(2);
                add(3);
                add(4);
                add(5);
            }
        };

        copy(dest, src);
        System.out.println(dest);
    }
```

What does `T` stand for in this scenario? Is there any why to get the `T` at runtime?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question properly. <T> is a generic type, but here `List<Number> dest` the type is `Number`, and here `List<Integer> src` the type is `Integer`? If you want to know the type of an item in the list you can simply use `yourList.get(x).getClass();`. However, note that if the list was of type `<Object>` for example, then each item in the list could be a different type.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the official java tutorial on the topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I think T is any type that that compiler can use to make the wildcards be true.  In this case T is probably `Number`.  <Number super Number> is OK if we accept that a class is super class of itself.  <Integer extends Number> I think is obviously true.  You can get a similar set of type expressions by setting T to Integer, which also works.